# Updating an existing installed addon

Tags: python, add-on

so I've made made an addon for blender, tested it and installed it on the target computer. On the dev computer, the script still is just loaded into the scripting Worspace and executed. But now I've made some improvements.

Do I have to uninstall the addon on the target system and install new version? Or can I just update the *.py files in the addon directory?

Comment: I think the preferred way is to remove the add-on, close Blender, launch Blender, and install the new version. Although with some add-ons you can just install the new version and the previous version will be overwritten without error. I guess it depends on how you deal with unregistering the add-on, what are the dependencies, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Then un-/reinstalling seems to be the best way. Actually the dependencies won't change (as it seems at the moment).

Comment: You can just update the .py files. Afterwards, either reload scripts or just close/re-open Blender.

Comment: Do either. There are pros and cons of both. For the organized: Using `git` as a version control system on your dev machine would be my 2c worth.  Can update addon from it on your prod, or roll back to a prior version. The vim editor does this well with plugins, which are updated from the repo.  There are some qas here re blender & git, or a git-load on SO.

Comment: whoops, thought it was only tagged addon, and python tag closed rather than a single vote to close. If you feel this does not answer your question, please add a comment saying so.